# HTML form not sending post through submit

Tags: php, html, forms

I have checked all the solutions on Stack overflow...and I am meeting all I need. Still my HTML form is not sending post request.here is my code.

This is create_blog.php page ..this includes

```
<?php include_once ('blog_controller.php'); ?>
```

at top.

```
<form action="create_blog.php" method="post">
   <div class="form-row form-row">
      <div class="form-controls">
         <input type="text" name="title" class="field form-control input-lg" required id="field-fname" value="" placeholder="Title*" />
      </div>
      <!-- /.form-controls --> 
   </div>
   <!-- /.form-row -->

   <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-controls">
         <textarea class="textarea" name="body"  required id="field-message" placeholder="Content*"></textarea>
      </div>
      <!-- /.form-controls --> 
   </div>
   <!-- /.form-row -->

   <?php
   if (isset($error)) {
       echo '<div class="alert alert-error">' . $error . ' </div>';
   }
   if (isset($success)) {
       echo '<div class="alert alert-success">' . $success . ' </div>';
   }
   ?>
   <div class="form-actions">
      <input type="submit" value="CREATE NOW" name="add_blog" class="button btn-purple btn-small" />
   </div>
   <!-- /.form-actions -->
</form>
```

Here is blog_controller.php

```
<?php
include_once ('ManageBlogs.php');
$init = new ManageBlogs();


//CREATE NEW BLOG

if (isset($_POST['add_blog'])) {
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $body = $_POST['body'];
    $date_created = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');


    if (empty($title)) {
        $error = 'You must provide a title to add this blog.';
    } else {
        $create_code = $init->addNewCode($title, $body, $date_created);

        if ($create_code == 1) {
            $success = 'Blog '.$title.' added Successfully';
        } else {
            $error = 'Error adding Blog. Please Try Again.';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Still it's sending no POST request on submit button click.

Comment: Let me see if I understand you correctly. You're saying that if you - for example - press Enter while the "title" field is focused, the request goes through, but if you press the submit nothing happens? If that is the case, try to check if there isn't something intercepting this click. JavaScript would be the first culprit to come to mind, but sometimes it's also worth starting your browser without plugins (or a different browser altogether) and checking the page again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change :

```
<form action = 'create_blog.php' ...>
```

To :

```
<form action = 'blog_controller.php' ...>
```

You have handled the form in blog_controller.php
but the action of the form is create_blog.php

Also check if on javscript side you have this code :

```
event.preventDefault();
```

This javascript coding also prevents the form to transfer the control to PHP coding once the button is fired .

Comment: I have already included that at the top of the page using include...and it is listening to my button click...i have already tried what you said..it did not work. The thing is clicking submit button is not sending any post request.

Comment: Inside blog_controller.php try this code var_dump($_POST['add_blog']); inside your first if condition and check if your getting value of your button

Comment: event.preventDefault(); was the culprit...thanks for great help.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is, you want to send data from login.php to login_controller.php, right?
So the action in the form is going to be 'login_controller.php', not 'create_blog.php'.

Comment: I have already included that file at the top to listen to the button click through post event. The problem is on click of button...nothing happens.

Comment: You mean blog_controller.php? I tried a piece of your code and it worked for me. I just changed the form action to be action='login_controller.php', instead of 'create_blog.php', and it worked perfectly. What do you have in blog_controller?

Comment: Hi Licky... thanks for your efforts... I am having a strange issue...I could not figure it out. The thing is that on submitting the form...no post request goes for button...but it goes for my text inputs.... your solution did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've gone through your code and it is working without any issues. Since I'm not including `ManageBlogs.php` which means it may cause this error. Try to remove the file inclusion and check again. If you are getting the output which means, some unwanted internal redirects are removing the POST values.

Here is the code which I tried and it is working.

```
<?php 

include_once ('blog_controller.php'); 

if (isset($title)) {
   echo 'Title: '.$title;
}
?>
<form action="create_blog.php" method="post">
   <div class="form-row form-row">
      <div class="form-controls">
         <input type="text" name="title" class="field form-control input-lg" required id="field-fname" value="" placeholder="Title*" />
      </div>
      <!-- /.form-controls --> 
   </div>
   <!-- /.form-row -->

   <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-controls">
         <textarea class="textarea" name="body"  required id="field-message" placeholder="Content*"></textarea>
      </div>
      <!-- /.form-controls --> 
   </div>
   <!-- /.form-row -->
    <?php
    if (isset($error)) {
       echo '<div class="alert alert-error">' . $error . ' </div>';
    }
    if (isset($success)) {
       echo '<div class="alert alert-success">' . $success . ' </div>';
    }
   ?>
   <div class="form-actions">
      <input type="submit" value="CREATE NOW" name="add_blog" class="button btn-purple btn-small" />
   </div>
   <!-- /.form-actions -->
</form>
```

blog_controller.php

```
<?php
// include_once ('ManageBlogs.php');
// $init = new ManageBlogs();

if (isset($_POST['title'])) {
    $title =  $_POST['title'];  
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : Remove `<?php include_once ('blog_controller.php'); ?>` from top and change action from `create_blog.php` to `blog_controller.php`

As I got from your question you want data from current form to `blog_controller.php` where you have code to do something.